# How to log from Java UDF installed in DB2

Tags: java, db2, user-defined-functions

I have a JAVA UDF installed in DB2 10.5 and everything works ok. 
But i have some catch blocks in which i would like to log some info along with the stack trace. Question is how can i log them and in which db2 log file will these info be printed.

I tried using System.out.println and looking into db2diag log file, but nothing was printed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a java routine for Db2-LUW, the output to System.out.println will never appear in the Db2 diagnostics file, and if you are wise you should not force that.

There's more than one way to handle it.

One way is for your routine to redirect stdout before calling System.out.println.
Example

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("java_routine_log.txt")));
```

In the above example the filename is unqualified so by default it will appear in the instance diagnostics directory (by default ~${DB2INSTANCE}/sqllib/db2dump ).

Another way is to use a configurable logging framework which lets you control logging locations and other details for tracing.

Other ways exist also.